# save checkbox values with pdo in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

I can't save the values in checkbox into my db...always save "array" and not the values..

in fiddler I see that the form catch the values but when the data go to save.php file the values change to array... can you give me a hand with this please?

here is the form:

```
    <form name="esq" id="esq" method="post">
    <div class="row-fluid grid">
    <div class="span4">
    <label><b><?php echo $translate->__('Gestas Previas'); ?>: </b></label><input type="text" class="span3" value="" name="gestas" /></div>
    <div class="span4">
    <label><b><?php echo $translate->__('Abortos'); ?>: </b></label><input type="text" class="span3" value="" name="abortos" /></div>
    <div class="span4">
    <label><b><?php echo $translate->__('3 espontaneos consecutivos'); ?>: </b></label><input type="text" class="span3" value="" name="esp_conse" /></div>
    </div>

----------HERE START THE CHECKBOX-------------
    <div class="row-fluid grid">
    <label class="control-label"><b><?php echo $translate->__('Ultimo Previo'); ?></b></label>
    <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
    <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox1" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="2500g" name="seleccion[]" type="checkbox"></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('2500 g'); ?>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
    <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox2" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="4500g" name="seleccion[]" type="checkbox"></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('4500 g'); ?>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
    <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox3" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="pre_eclam" name="seleccion[]" type="checkbox"></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Preclampsia-eclampsia'); ?>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
    <div id="uniform-inlineCheckbox4" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="cesarea" name="seleccion[]" type="checkbox"></span></div> <?php echo $translate->__('Cesárea'); ?>
    </label>
    </div>
    </div><br />
----------HERE FINISH THE CHECKBOX-------------
..............
```

here is the code:

```
<?php 
include_once("confs.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
        try{
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO GESTACION (gestas, abortos, esp_conse, seleccion, partos, vaginal, cesareas, nac_vivos, nac_muertos, viven, semana, des_semana, f_ult_parto, f_ult_pap, fur, fpp, edad_gesta, pesofeto, tallafeto, imc, toxoide, influenza, otras, medicament) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['gestas'], $_POST['abortos'], $_POST['esp_conse'], $_POST['seleccion'], $_POST['partos'], $_POST['vaginal'], $_POST['cesareas'], $_POST['nac_vivos'], $_POST['nac_muertos'], $_POST['viven'], $_POST['semana'], $_POST['des_semana'], $_POST['f_ult_parto'], $_POST['f_ult_pap'], $_POST['fur'], $_POST['fpp'], $_POST['edad_gesta'], $_POST['pesofeto'], $_POST['tallafeto'], $_POST['imc'], $_POST['toxoide'], $_POST['influenza'], $_POST['otras'], $_POST['medicament'])));
        $dbSuccess = true;     
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
}
   $dbh = null;  
}
?>
```

all other data save nice into db.

Comment: You are using the array format for your `seleccion` checkboxes, ie `name="seleccion[]"`. This means that `$_POST['seleccion']` will be an array. You need to decide how you're going to deal with multiple selections / values within this field.

Comment: @Phil that part I don't know how to do it...

Comment: How should multiple checkbox selections be saved? Do you want to simply save them as a comma separated list in the `seleccion` column, eg `2500g,4500g,cesarea` or should they be saved via a *many-to-many* relationship with the `GESTACION` row?

Comment: only with the comma... is for each female patient the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the extra information in your comments, I'd say you simply want this

```
$seleccion = is_array($_POST['seleccion'])
    ? implode(', ', $_POST['seleccion'])
    : $_POST['seleccion'];

// snip

$statement->execute(array(
    $_POST['gestas'],
    $_POST['abortos'],
    $_POST['esp_conse'],
    $seleccion, ...
```

This will save any checkbox selections as a comma separated list with the `GESTACION` table row